# how to find view by its view class in android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am inspired by the following code:

```
@Test
public void onType() throws Exception {
    ...
    onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)).perform(typeText("a"));
    ...
}
```

How to get view with view class in activity, I think it's useful to control 3rd custom view

Answer (score 0):

The code you are telling about is a part of [Espresso testing framework](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/cheatsheet/index.html). It's used for instrumentation UI-testing, but it is not common usage for simple app.

You able to setup dependency for this library even for your app (not for test-module) like this:

```
dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

But i think such approaches have bad impact to performance (perhaps using simple view iteration under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

if you have an object reference for some class for example class derived from View.class

```
View someView <- by  findViewById(int),  getView(), getRootView() etc // any method that return view
```

you can check if you can assign it to some other class by an up cast - in this way by moving from right to left ( some examples bellow ):

```
EditText <- TextView <- View 
FrameLayout <- ViewGroup  <- View
NumberPicker <- LinearLayou <- ViewGroup <- View
```

example application:

```
// get View class reference by call to find view by id 
View view = findViewById(R.id.someView);
if(view!=null) {
     Class viewClass = view.getClass()
     //  check if we can assign edit text class  to this class ???  
     if(EditText.class.isAssingableFrom(viewClass)) {
           // u can cast it to edit text and do some stuff with edit text  class as we did up casting  while in this case it is allowed:
           EditText editText = (EditText) view;
            editText.setText(String);

     }
}
```

this way we will not rise an exception when for example we do this sort of cast without any check:

```
 ((EditText) view).setText(String);
```

if view class is type other as EditText or is not derived from edit text class exception will be thrown.

from Class implementation:

```
public final class Class<T> implements Serializable, AnnotatedElement, GenericDeclaration, Type {

...

 /**
 * Can {@code c}  be assigned to this class? For example, String can be assigned to Object
 * (by an upcast), however, an Object cannot be assigned to a String as a potentially exception
 * throwing downcast would be necessary. Similarly for interfaces, a class that implements (or
 * an interface that extends) another can be assigned to its parent, but not vice-versa. All
 * Classes may assign to themselves. Classes for primitive types may not assign to each other.
 *
 * @param c the class to check.
 * @return {@code true} if {@code c} can be assigned to the class
 *         represented by this {@code Class}; {@code false} otherwise.
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code c} is {@code null}.
 */
public boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> c) {
```

see also:

[The Type Comparison Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 0):

following code should work:

```
static class FindV {
    Context ctx;
    ViewGroup vg;
    Class<? extends View> targetK;


    public FindV(ViewGroup vg, Class<? extends View> targetK) {
        ctx = vg.getContext();
        this.vg = vg;
        this.targetK = targetK;
    }

    ArrayList<View> vs = new ArrayList<View>();

    //        public static <T extends View> ArrayList<T> findV(ViewGroup vg, Class<T> targetK) {
    ArrayList<View> st() {
        st(vg);
        return vs;
    }

    void st(ViewGroup vg) {
        int cc = vg.getChildCount();
        if (cc > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
                View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                if (v.getClass() == targetK) {
                    vs.add(v);
                }
            }

            if (vs.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
                    View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                    if (ancestorKs(v).contains(targetK)) {
                        vs.add(v);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
                View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
                if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    st((ViewGroup) v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static <T extends View> ArrayList<T> findV(ViewGroup vg, Class<T> targetK) {
    return (ArrayList<T>) new FindV(vg, targetK).st();
}
```